# Ionic Cordova Angular - local device images don't show in img ng-src

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am storing local images on the device (iOS) using the `cordova.file.DataDirectory` location.

My rendered HTML is showing the right path to the file (and I know the file exists)

Controller:

```
$scope.IMAGE_PATH = fileResult.toURL();
```

Template:

```
<img ng-src="{{IMAGE_PATH}}">
```

Rendered Result:

```
<img ng-src="file:///var/mobile/Applications/A5804B42-6818-4695-AA9D-7EA92CAC870B/Library/NoCloud/16_556118a379a45.jpg" src="file:///var/mobile/Applications/A5804B42-6818-4695-AA9D-7EA92CAC870B/Library/NoCloud/16_556118a379a45.jpg" class="">
```

But my image is not showing (I get the missing image icon)

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Are you sure your file exists ? If yes, then please check your folder permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was created earlier in the process as the file saved locally on the device was an empty file.